# Can a Dhampir bite themselves to get the benefits of their Vampiric Bite?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits

The Dhampir lineage from *Van Richten's Guide to Ravenloft* has the following Vampiric Bite feature:

> Your fanged bite is a natural weapon, which counts as a simple melee weapon with which you are proficient. You add your Constitution modifier, instead of your Strength modifier, to the attack and damage rolls when you attack with this bite. It deals 1d4 piercing damage on a hit. While you are missing half or more of your hit points, you have advantage on attack rolls you make with this bite.
>
> When you attack with this bite and hit a creature that isn’t a Construct or an Undead, you can empower yourself in one of the following ways of your choice:
>
> - You regain hit points equal to the piercing damage dealt by the bite.
> - You gain a bonus to the next ability check or attack roll you make; the bonus equals the piercing damage dealt by the bite.
>
> You can empower yourself with this bite a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

Is it possible for a wounded Dhampir to bite themselves and get the bonus to their next ability check or attack roll?

Comment: If they have temp HP, they could use this to convert it to permanent HP, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Sure. Go ahead and make an attack roll.

There is no rule that you cannot attack yourself, but all the usual rules for making an attack apply. You must make an attack roll against your own armor class. On a hit, you deal 1d4+CON piercing damage to yourself, and can choose to gain a obnus on your next ability check.

For a more thorough discussion of attacking yourself, see here: [Can a PC attack themselves with an unarmed strike?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153229/can-a-pc-attack-themselves-with-an-unarmed-strike)

#### This works because Wizards removed the feature that prevented it from the UA version.

In the Unearthed Arcana version of the Dhampir, we see:

> **Type:** Humanoid and Undead

Your type was humanoid *and undead*, meaning the UA Dhampir is not an eligible target for its own bite. Thanks Wizards of the Coast.

Comment: B A L A N C E D  G A M E P L A Y. On the other hand, it does kind of fill the "Blood Knight" archetype, where they have more powerful attacks at the cost of their won health.